# Multithreaded file reading, does seek & read need critical section?

Tags: c#, multithreading, file-io

I have a file that will be read from multiple threads, do I need to put each seek and read into a critical section?

```
stream.Seek(seekStart, SeekOrigin.Begin);
stream.Read();
stream.Seek(seekNext, SeekOrigin.Current);
stream.Read();
```

or

```
lock(fileLock)
{
    stream.Seek(seekStart, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Read();
    stream.Seek(seekNext, SeekOrigin.Current);
    stream.Read();
}
```

Obviously what I'm trying to avoid is the following situation:

```
.
.
 Thread A: Seek
 <- Preempted ->
 Thread B: Seek
 Thread B: Read
 <- Preempted ->
 Thread A: Read  (Will this be reading from the wrong location?)
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your streams will be separate objects in separate threads, you should be OK without making it critical. Each stream should hold its own seek location, and so should not interfere with the others.

This assumes that you are declaring all of your variables within the class object, and not static.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you're modifying an object which is shared across threads, you need a critical section.

If the `stream` variable is being shared (referring to the same object), then yes.

If each thread has its own `stream` variable (not referring to the same object), then no.

Answer (score 0):

if it is the same stream you would need for each seek and read to be in a critical section...

Alternatively you can use `MemoryMappedFile` (ne in .NET 4)... this allows multiple threads to access it without crisitcal section because it maps the file into RAM and then you can random access its content...

Comment: I'm in 3.5 so I may use interop at some point to memory map  but not yet

Comment: how big is the file ? you could even load it into a byte[] and read from that array from different threads in parallel

Comment: I do not want to load the entire thing into memory, otherwise yes that owuld be nice

Answer (score 0):

MSDN say for FileStream"

> When a FileStream object does not have an exclusive hold on its
>   handle, another thread could access the file handle concurrently and
>   change the position of the operating system's file pointer that is
>   associated with the file handle. In this case, the cached position in
>   the FileStream object and the cached data in the buffer could be
>   compromised. The FileStream object routinely performs checks on
>   methods that access the cached buffer to assure that the operating
>   system's handle position is the same as the cached position used by
>   the FileStream object.
>
> If an unexpected change in the handle position is detected in a call
>   to the Read method, the .NET Framework discards the contents of the
>   buffer and reads the stream from the file again. This can affect
>   performance, depending on the size of the file and any other processes
>   that could affect the position of the file stream.

So at least, you can have performance issues. For performance, the best solution is to use Asynchronuous I/O (BeginRead, EndRead)